# GWT Suggestbox with Smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am facing a problem that I can't see the drop down list of the GWT Suggestbox.
I am adding a GWT Suggestbox into SmartGWT's VLayout. Then I can see the textbox of the Suggestbox. But when I input some data, I can't see the suggestions provided.
Is this because I am using the SmartGWT VLayout? Could anyone tell me how to solve it? Thanks.

---

Sorry, the above question is not clear enough. What I mean is I add a SuggestBox into a layout with small height. Then I can see the the SuggestBox's TextBox part and part of the suggestion and the rest of the suggestion seems hide under other layout. Below is my code:

```
VLayout mainLayout = new VLayout();
mainLayout.setHeight100();
mainLayout.setWidth100();

MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
oracle.add("a");
oracle.add("aa");
oracle.add("aaa");
oracle.add("aaaa");
oracle.add("aaaaa");
oracle.add("aaaaaa");
oracle.add("aaaaaaa");
SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(oracle, new TextBox());
VLayout suggestBoxLayout = new VLayout(); 
suggestBoxLayout.setHeight("10%");
suggestBoxLayout.addMember(box);


VLayout body = new VLayout();
body.setBackgroundColor("#3B5998");
body.setHeight("90%");

mainLayout.addMember(body);
mainLayout.addMember(suggestBoxLayout);
```

So when I enter `a` into the SuggestBox, I can only see `a, aa, aaa` and the rest suggestions are hide by the `body`.

Comment: THere are Zindex problem between gwt and smartgwt if you want to have your GWT widget on the top of the stack you have to give them a high Z index.

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE I try that. But still the same problem. Could you tell me how you set the CSS style?

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE Thanks for your advice! I set z-index to 1000000! Then the problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from Alain, I add `.gwt-SuggestBoxPopup {z-index: 1000000;}` into my CSS. Then I solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This may be zIndex related, but there's no reason to use GWT's SuggestBox and run into problems like this.  Use SmartGWT's ComboBoxItem.  If you don't want a drop-down control to appear at the end of the text entry area, call setShowPickerIcon(false).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is I need a multivalue suggestion box. I found there is one created by other people. And its base element is a GWT SuggestBox. Thats why I need to mix GWT with SmartGWT.

Comment: SmartGWT has a MultiComboBox here: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#multicombobox_category_new

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with little bit of code.
Before stopping to mix Smartgwt with Gwt I integrated some code which was using GWt suggestBox and it was working....
(Why don't you use the Smartgwt selectitem it does the job?)
Regards

Alain

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I have added more details in my question. Could you have a look again? Thanks.