# SmartGWT SelectItem overlapping GWT DateBox

Tags: css, gwt, z-index, smartgwt, datebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT Suggestbox with Smartgwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713770/gwt-suggestbox-with-smartgwt)

I have two GWT DateBoxes and one SmartGWT SelectItem for multiple selects with an appearance of PICKLIST.

The problem is that when a DateBox is clicked and the DatePicker is shown, it is BEHIND the SelectItem, as shown in this screenshot:

EDIT: As I do not have 10 reputation yet, I can't post the image. So here is the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI6cz.png

Here's the code for the SelectItem:

```
    selectItemFilterList.setTitle("Filter:");  
    selectItemFilterList.setMultiple(true);
    selectItemFilterList.setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.PICKLIST);
    selectItemFilterList.setWidth(250);        
    ... values are set here ...
    selectItemFilterList.setValueMap(valueMap);

    DynamicForm filterForm = new DynamicForm();
    filterForm.setItems(selectItemFilterList);
    filterForm.setStyleName(style.inline());
    addToFilterPanel(filterForm);
```

Can I fix this issue somehow?

Comment: I tried adding a CSS style to both the DateBox and the DatePicker with a z-index of 1000001, as suggested by various sources, but this does not work for me.

Comment: I got it working, the solution is to set the z-index of the DateBox Popup.

Comment: You should search for this kind of question first. Look at this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713770/gwt-suggestbox-with-smartgwt).

Comment: Well I did, but haven't found that, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I had to set the z-index of the DateBox **Popup** instead of the DateBox or DatePicker!

After adding the following to my application's css file in the war directory everything works as intended:

```
    .dateBoxPopup {
        z-index: 1000001;
    }
```